# Shiny R Add tooltips while hovering over the map

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, tooltip

Image of the map[image: Image of the map]So I created a map with shiny r. However, I am trying to add tooltips that will display the information when a person hovers over the country. For instance: when it goes on to russia it will display the data on russia as a pop up or tooltip.

I couldn't succeed in doing it. I found couple of codes that adds tooltips to the sidebars however I want to display it on the map while hovering over the countries.

```
> library(shiny)
> library(shinyBS)
> ui<-fluidPage(
+   mainPanel(
+     tabsetPanel(id="tp",
+                 tabPanel("Map View", plotOutput("mPlot", height="560px", width="950px"))
+     )
+   )))


> sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(data, joinCode='NAME', nameJoinColumn='Country.code')

> server<- function(input, output, session){
+   output$mPlot <- renderPlot({
+     mapParams <- mapPolys(sPDF, 
nameColumnToPlot="Truth.Commission.Total", mapRegion="world",
+                           missingCountryCol="dark grey", catMethod = 
"fixedWith", numCats=20, 
+                           colourPalette=brewer.pal(20,"YlOrRd"),
+                           addLegend=TRUE,
+                           oceanCol="light blue")
+     mtext("[Grey Color: No Data Available]",side=1,line=-1)
+   })
+ }

> shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

The prior general solutions was made with

```
>addTooltip(session, id = "someInput", title = "This is an input.",
       placement = "left", trigger = "hover")
```

However, as the countries on map does not have explicit id's displayed on the page, but has the data when plotting the map this solution did not work for me.